# Web API that accepts JSON object as input parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Rest API that can accept the JSON object query the database and return the JSON response. The JSON that needs to be sent as input parameter is like below

```
{
 data: [
 {
 "barCode" : "ABC",
 "JR_No"   : "0001"
 }]}
```

I have created the class for the JSON like below

```
  public class Datum
 {
 public string barCode { get; set; }
 public string JR_No { get; set; }
 }

 public class RootObject
  {
 public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
 }
```

Below is the query I need to use

```
 "SELECT * from Name_View where Stk_Number = @JR_No ";
```

How I pass in the whole JSON as input parameter here. Or should I give the Model class name as input parameter below.

```
public class GetJStrainNameController : ApiController
{
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetName(??????)
{
```

Also how can I parse through the input parameter so I can get the JR_NO to use in the query.

Comment: How are you going to send JSON in a GET request?

Comment: What does a query have to do with your question? Also, you should read basic parameter binding in ASP.NET Web Api

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not sure how to do that too, Is that not possible? I tried getting the string and it worked fine.

Comment: `public HttpResponseMessage GetName(RootObject theObject)`, surely? Then the model binder will deserialise into a C# object for you automatically. That's what any Web API tutorial worth following will show you, I think. Also I think you'll probably need to make it a POST if you want to send a big JSON object like that.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks. But where should I be using the POST?

Comment: `[HttpPost]` instead of `[HttpGet]`. It changes the HTTP method which the action will respond to. I suggest you get up to speed on the concept of that if you're not sure what I'm talking about. And then whatever code you use to make the request and send the JSON should make sure it specifies the POST method as the one to be used when making the request.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use List in input and no need to create separate class RootObject for it(unless you use it somewhere else)